# hiding movieControl in iphone OS 3.2 or later

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I saw this example on appsmuck.com for seamless video looping, it works fine on iphoneOS 3.0
but doesn't works on 3.2 or above :(

It says `movieControlMode is deprecated`

http://appsamuck.com/day26.html

can someone tell me how to hide the controls in iphoneOS 3.2 or above.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok try this one:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 32000
    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
#else
    moviePlayer.movieControlMode = MPMovieControlModeHidden; 
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

you can replace that line with theMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

Comment: nope its not working... :(

i wrote..
`moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

Comment: then try moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlModeHidden;

Comment: In previous answer i just gave the example to use the controlStyle. If you set the MPMovieControlStyleNone. It will hide the controls. Use this theMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

Comment: you should use my #if statement if you still want to support versions prior 3.2